# Registre de "faire passer"

Tags: registre

Est-ce le registre de la phrase :

> Je souhaite faire passer un test aux étudiants durant cette semaine.

considéré soutenu ? Peut-on employer la construction *faire+infinitif* lors d'un discours normal, des e-mails, etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il me semble que le registre de cette locution verbale permette de l'employer  dans des contextes assez formels. Cependant, dans un texte de règlementation, par exemple, une expression plus formelle, telle que « **soumettre les étudiants à un test** » sera préférable.

Oui, « faire » suivi d'un infinitif s'emploie couramment ; le registre est celui de la langue courante ; cependant, il est reconnu qu'un terme de substitution n'utilisant pas « faire » relève d'un meilleur style. L'un de mes professeurs de français des classes de collège conseillait d'éviter ce verbe à tout faire ; il ne faut pas cependant prendre cela trop strictement.